# Receiving custom WebHooks in a Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, asp.net-web-api2, webhooks

I am working to make an internal application available from an external location. To accomplish this I’m looking into different options like the use of a rest API or using a socket server which can be placed between the old application and the database on the server. One of the concerns of the end product is that if multiple users alter the same data and sent this to the server that there is the possibility that they overwrite each other’s changes. The planned approach for this is have a server sided log for data changes, and notify the user that relevant data has been altered to give them the choice to reload their form. The latter part is the issue from which my question has come forth. Unlike sockets web protocols do not work bidirectional. Potential fixes that I have found are polling, framing and WebHook of which the latter seem to be the most efficient.

However looking at the different available WebHook receiver samples they seem to have something in common. They use either MVC or WebAPI and all have an altered `WebConfig` in which the method `config.InitializeCustomWebHooks();` has been added.

I’ve been trying to find a way to add this in by altering the `Program.cs` without success.

Also I’ve tried to find a method that has to do with Hooks using the `HttpClient` (which I’ve used for the rest of my demo application so far), `WebClient` and `HttpResponse`. However this search also did not bear any fruits. Also the only post of someone who tried to accomplish something similar (have a windows forms application listen to GitHub) that I found got a [response][1] that made me believe that webhooks and windows forms just don’t go together.

This search has ended with me wondering or:

Is it a possibility to consume an API 2 services WebHooks with a windows form application?
And if possible I would like to be informed how to do this?

For now my API 2 server has been pretty much altered according the example provided by [Asp.Net][2]
And my client has implemented the `CustomWebHookHandler` from the `CustomReceiver` from the same.

---

Edit for next issue:

note: both client and server contain the same packages as used in the repo as shown by Peter Bons.

The client contains a secret key within the `app.config`, matching the key within the subscribe method and the new `Startup.cs` has been called (I am able to sent echo's to the client sided hosted server) so that part is working. The registration class also matches up with the example repo

Client initiates the webhook with the following method:

```
public void SubscribeTo(String subscribeString)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result;

        // Create a webhook registration
        Registration registration = new Registration
        {
            WebHookUri = $"{adressReceiver}/api/webhooks/incoming/custom",

            Description = "A message is posted.",
            Secret = "12345678901234567890123456789012",

            Filters = new List<string> { "EmployeeChanged" }
        };

        result = client.PostAsJsonAsync(@"webhooks/registrations", registration).Result;
        string resultString = result.ToString();
    }
```

Where adress receiver is the same string that was used to start the echoable webservice.

Upon debugging the method the following actions server/client occur:
on the line containing `result =`  the server sided debug point in `CustomFilterProvider.GetFiltersAsync` get's triggered.

At the return method it shows that 1 filer was returned with the `Name`: `"EmployeeChanged"` back on the client the `resultString` contains the `StatusCode: Created`
During the method the client has the system output:

> ClientApp.exe Information: 0 : Registered 'IWebHookReceiver' instances with the following names: custom.
>
> ClientApp.exe Information: 0 : Processing incoming WebHook request with receiver 'custom' and id ''.
>
> ClientApp.exe Information: 0 : Registered configuration setting 'Custom' for ID '''.

And the server:
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured):

```
{
  "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.RemoteDependency",
  "time": "2017-09-12T10:16:25.8947601Z",
  "tags": {
    "ai.internal.nodeName": "PC-78.vericon.nl",
    "ai.operation.id": "1348c1c9-4b7a5ac6dd5f1940",
    "ai.cloud.roleInstance": "PC-78.vericon.nl",
    "ai.internal.sdkVersion": "rdddsd:2.4.1-1362"
  },
  "data": {
    "baseType": "RemoteDependencyData",
    "baseData": {
      "ver": 2,
      "name": "GET /api/webhooks/incoming/custom",
      "id": "|1348c1c9-4b7a5ac6dd5f1940.",
      "data":
        "http://localhost:55999/api/webhooks/incoming/custom?echo=e9f7b03ca8aa4226a7a9dfc99dacff16",
      "duration": "00:00:00.2046329",
      "resultCode": "200",
      "success": true,
      "type": "Http",
      "target": "localhost:55999",
      "properties": { "DeveloperMode": "true" }
    }
  }
}
```

Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured):

```
{
  "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Request",
  "time": "2017-09-12T10:14:50.0204275Z",
  "tags": {
    "ai.internal.nodeName": "PC-78.vericon.nl",
    "ai.operation.name": "POST /api/webhooks/registrations",
    "ai.operation.id": "lXKbEdh4GOU=",
    "ai.location.ip": "::1",
    "ai.cloud.roleInstance": "PC-78.vericon.nl",
    "ai.internal.sdkVersion": "web:2.4.1-1362"
  },
  "data": {
    "baseType": "RequestData",
    "baseData": {
      "ver": 2,
      "id": "|lXKbEdh4GOU=.1348c1c8_",
      "name": "POST /api/webhooks/registrations",
      "duration": "00:01:36.1228603",
      "success": true,
      "responseCode": "201",
      "url": "http://localhost:55997/api/webhooks/registrations",
      "properties": { "DeveloperMode": "true" }
    }
  }
}
```

After a bit of research my reasoning for this output is that the server sends an echo request to the ip given by the client to see or it is a reachable destination. The code `created` also implies that the server found this adress because otherwise a code `BadRequest` would occur

So I think that the webhook get's correctly established futher on in the application I have got a method that makes a post request to the server. I put a debug point in the server sided method to see what happens (there's also is a debug point in my client handler).

after doing the client sided action that should get me in my controller the debug point within indeed get's triggered in my method:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Employee e)
    {
        await this.NotifyAsync(CustomFilterProvider.EmployeeChanged, new { Employee = e });
        if (EmployeeModifier.updateEmployee(e))
        {
            log.Info("User: " + User.Identity.Name + " Updated an employee with the following new value " + Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(e));
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            log.Error("User: " + User.Identity.Name + " failed to update an employee");
            return BadRequest();
        }         
    }
```

when stepping through it it follows the route towards to return `Ok()`
the client receives the system output:

> ClientApp.exe Information: 0 : Processing incoming WebHook request with receiver 'custom' and id ''.

However the debug point within the clients handler never get's triggered.
the handler for now looks like:

```
class CustomWebHookHandler : WebHookHandler
{
    public CustomWebHookHandler()
    {

    }

    public override Task ExecuteAsync(string generator, WebHookHandlerContext context)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("In handler");

        
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

My client `startup.cs` `Configuration` method looks like:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        var controllerType = typeof(WebHookReceiversController);

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "DefaultApi",
                "api/{controller}/{id}",
                new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

        config.InitializeReceiveCustomWebHooks();

        var traceWriter = config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        traceWriter.IsVerbose = true;
        traceWriter.MinimumLevel = TraceLevel.Error;

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

So that contains the `var controllerType`

I hope this is enough relevant code for you, my fear is that my server is only sending echo's/ping requests to my client.

But I don't know how to change that since I've tried both `NotifyAsync` and `NotifyAllAsync`, with and without `Filter(` in client `Registration` class instance). The clients OWIN hosts keeps up for sure since it is echo able and the client output shows that it actually does receive a message from the server but that's where I'm crashed.

Comment: It is possible, I did it using a Console App so it should work in a winforms app as well. See [this repo](https://github.com/Expecho/Self-Hosted-Asp.Net-WebHooks)

Comment: Hello Peter, Thank you very much this example does indeed show off the basics that I'm trying to implement in my application.

Comment: I see that you added your own startup.cs to the project and call it from the program.cs which definitely seems to make the difference. Thanks! I think this should suffice to get me started :)

Comment: Glad to help. Succes with your project.

Comment: Thank you, got to work on it today again. Managed to get Oauth 2 running on my server so actually could get to the testing(friday I got a no authorized). For now the state is that when the client creates the webhook it get's a 201 created from the server. and when I do a NotifyAsync or a NotifyAllAsync on the server I get the status code ok back. Also if I open chrome and go to the clients local host with an echo it seems to work. The only thing is the clients CustomWebHookHandler never get's called. Could you give another hand? same handler called with:

Comment: await this.NotifyAsync(CustomFilterProvider.EmployeeChanged, new { Employee = e });
As stated the server get's a status code 'OK' back so I think my notify somehow is more like an echo then an actuall notify?

Comment: Ow yes my client actually does give the output:
ClientApp.exe Information: 0 : Processing incoming WebHook request with receiver 'custom' and id ''.

So it claims to receive and process the webhook request. However the debug points in my ExecuteAsync task from my CustomWebHookHandler : WebHookHandler never trigger neither do the console writelines in there get shown.

Comment: Hmm can you post the relevant code?

Comment: I can try, I'll edit my original question(more room for code) will start working on it right now

Comment: Okay, I hope that that is all the relevant code you needed, and I hope that you are able and willing to help me out a bit more.

Comment: I don't see any obvious flaws so far. Can you post the setup of the client app, like I did here? https://github.com/Expecho/Self-Hosted-Asp.Net-WebHooks/blob/master/Receiver/Program.cs. And of the server like here https://github.com/Expecho/Self-Hosted-Asp.Net-WebHooks/blob/master/WebApi/Program.cs

Comment: To verify, you only want to see the classes with that functionality but not the whole repository?

Comment: Wel,, if that is possible it would make things easier :-)

Comment: Ehhhhr possible yes, but I'll first have to tear out a bit of stuff like the hash method and the db connection stuff

Comment: Sorry for the wait but [here](https://github.com/ArnoDekkersLos/Webhookshelp) you go

Comment: Ow yes you can just enter any data in the login screen to sign in the method has been modified to always return a user. or remove the [Authorize] tag from the employeecontroller.

Comment: Sorry it took a while, had to find some time. The problem is the fact that [this class](https://github.com/ArnoDekkersLos/Webhookshelp/blob/master/ClientApp/ClientApp/WebHooks/CustomWebHookHandler.cs) is not public. Mark it as public and you'll get results. Asp.Net webhooks rely on reflection to find implementations of WebHookHandler classes

Comment: Thank you so very much! It sure is working now and I sure feel silly for not making that public. and about the response taking a while... Really no problem over your last few posts you just helped me from being hopeless on how to implement this in a windows form application to having a working webhook in there. I most certaintly am satisfied with the given help :)

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help.

Comment: Question futher down the line
It seems that if the behook server is hosted from an external computer (obviously) cannot resolve a localhost if that's given as the WebHookUri. It also seems that from my application if I give my WebApp.Start() method either my computers ip or my public ip with a port it throws a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException having to do with the HttpListener not having the required access


Is using a webhook to a 3rd party application feasable if the end users are on computers behind a router/firewall and only want to use the application so no IIS and stuff?